# react-navigation : How to hide one specific tabBar icon and label when a condtional statement is true

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using react-navigation. I have five icons for my bottomtabs navigator and I only want to show four icons(screen1,screen2,screen4 and screen 5) and hide the other(screen 3).

How can I hide the icon and the label of screen3 if and only if a conditional statement is true..?

This is my code:

```
const ButtomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    screen1: {
      screen: screen1,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: 'screen1',
        header: null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
        ),
      })
    },
    screen2: {
      screen: screen2,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarLabel: 'screen2',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
        ),
      }
    },
```

**I want to hide this screen3 icon and label if a conditional statement is true**

```
    screen3: {
          screen: screen3,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            tabBarLabel: 'screen3',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
            ),
          }
        },
    screen4: {
          screen: screen4,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            tabBarLabel: 'screen4',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
            ),
          }
        },
        screen5: {
          screen: screen5,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            tabBarLabel: 'screen5',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
            ),
          }
        },
      },
      {
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: '#16bb92',
        },
        shifting: true,
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution

```
const routes = (condition) => {
     let routes = {
         screen1: {
            screen: screen1,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                tabBarLabel: 'screen1',
                header: null,
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
                ),
            })
        },
        screen2: {
            screen: screen2,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
                tabBarLabel: 'screen2',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
                ),
            }
        },
        screen4: {
            screen: screen4,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
                tabBarLabel: 'screen4',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
                ),
            }
        },
        screen5: {
            screen: screen5,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null,
                tabBarLabel: 'screen5',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
                ),
            }
        }
     }

     if (condition) {
         routes["screen3"] = {
             screen: screen3,
             navigationOptions: {
             header: null,
             tabBarLabel: 'screen3',
             tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                 <FontAwesome name="gear" color={tintColor} size={30} />
             ),
         }
      }
   }

   return routes;
}
```

Then in your navigation

`const ButtomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(routes(/**Your condition**/, ....)`

Hope that help :)

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ''Object.keys(route.Config)') at  const ButtomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator

Comment: Can you show me how you call `createBottomTabNavigator` ?

Comment: const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator(routes(status),
{
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack ,
      navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home', 
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <FontAwesome name="home" color={tintColor} size={30} />
            )
          }
        },
  .......
}

Comment: why you using this `{ Home: { screen: HomeStack` inside config object ? I think it just `createBottomTabNavigator(routes(status), {
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: '#16bb92',
        },
        shifting: true,
      }); like your initial code.

Comment: i have been try all things as you mentioned above but having same issue..
typeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ''Object.keys(route.Config)')

Comment: Oh.. I forget :( I must `return routes` at the end of routes function :( just edited :( I think this probably work now :) what wrong with me today :((

Comment: not work even after add a return statement in the routes function..